# An example for asp.net 4.5 using Microsoft.WebSockets NuGet Package

Tags: asp.net, websocket, nuget-package

Can someone give me a reference to an article\sample code which uses html 5 web socket with the help of asp.net and Microsoft.WebSockets NuGet Package.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Microsoft.WebSockets package basically allows you to write an event-driven WebSocket application.  See http://alexjmackey.wordpress.com/2012/05/01/websockets-with-asp-net-4-5-and-visual-studio-11/ for an example which uses the package to implement a simple chat server.

Answer (score 1):

MDSN code gallery of course: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US/samplesgallery?query=WebSockets&refinement=203&beta=0&ac=8

NuGet is only a (rather useful) tool

Comment: Andrei, I heard like the .net inbuilt WebSocket support is very minimal, but their Nuget package release has simplified a lot of work. your link shows websocket usgae but not using Nuget package.